# Как выполнить приведение параметризованных типов при 'Unchecked assignment'?

Tags: java, generics

Как правильно выполнить приведение типов в следующей функции:

```
public static <T> Dao<T> getDao(Class<T> cl){
    for(Dao dao : daoList){
        if (cl == dao.getParameterizedClass())
            return dao;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Дело в том, что в строке `return dao` слово `dao` выделяется и появляется предупреждение `Unchecked assignment: 'dao.Dao' to 'dao.Dao<T>`.

Вот так выглядит класс, содержащий эту функцию:

```
public abstract class DaoFactory {

    private static final List<Dao<?>> daoList = Arrays.asList(
            new DaoImpl<>(Person.class)    
    );

    public static <T> Dao<T> getDao(Class<T> cl){
        for(Dao dao : daoList){
            if (cl == dao.getParameterizedClass())
                return dao;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

А это интерфейс Dao:

```
public interface Dao<T> {  
    Class<T> getParameterizedClass();
}
```

и его реализация:

```
public class DaoImpl<T> implements Dao<T> {

    private Class<T> parameterizedClass;

    DaoImpl(Class<T> cl){
        this.parameterizedClass = cl;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getParameterizedClass() {
        return parameterizedClass;
    }
}
```

Разумеется, можно сделать подавление предупреждения, или сделать возвращаемый тип непараметризованным - не `Dao<T>`, а просто `Dao`. Есть ли ещё способ устранить предупреждение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Связано это с тем, что во время выполнения у JVM нет информации о дженериках, из-за чего приведение типов в подобных ситуациях считается небезопасным. Логику приложения можно написать так, чтобы реальных проблем не возникало, не смотря на это предупреждение. Но значительно правильнее для каждого типа будет иметь свою реализацию `Dao`, например для `Person`:

```
public class PersonDao implements Dao<Person> {
    // methods
}
```

А общую функциональность, если таковая есть, можно реализовать в каком-нибудь абстрактном классе.

Comment: пришел к такому же выводу. Жаль, конечно, что необходимо создавать кучу классов. Думал, что можно обойтись более изящным решением.

Answer (score 1):

Только так можно избавиться от предупреждения:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Dao<T> getDao(Class<T> cl) {
        for (Dao dao : daoList) {
            if (cl == dao.getParameterizedClass())
                return (Dao<T>) dao;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Так вы говорите компилятору, что знаете что делаете и он об этом методе вас не информирует.

Вообще то ваш код в строгом смысле не типобезопасен. Тк в списке могут храниться Dao параметризированные абсолютно любым значением `List<Dao<?>>`.

Comment: я это понимаю, но думал, что есть способ написать типобезопасный код.